# Emoji converter

Tags: python, decode, encode

How can I convert this string in python3 `''` into this `'%F0%9F%91%80%F0%9F%A5%B6'` ? Would like to do this with any emojis

Comment: No, this is not UTF-8! UTF-8 doesn't use `%xx` to represent the value of a byte in hex. However (without checking), it seems based on UTF-8. If you know the receiving side and you have documentation what it expects, you should be able to figure out the according encoding function.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you, I will try to find anything about it then

Comment: To be clear, the string `''`is _already_ in UTF-8. Because your python is running in an environment (terminal, browser, whatever) that is also UTF-8, you see the emoji when Python sends the string. But UTFs are about how Unicode text turns into bytes, not about translating those byte values into hexadecimal numbers. Based on the use of `%` as the escape, what you want is [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If percentage encoding is what you are after, `urllib` module in Python could help.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

**Python 3:**

```py
text = ''
import urllib.parse
print(urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

Returns

```
%F0%9F%91%80%F0%9F%A5%B6
```

Comment: Be advised that `parse.quote` doesn't just do Emojis and other "fancy" Unicode characters. It also turns spaces and regular punctuation marks into the `%xx` form. So the end result is not very human-readable.